# Trying to produce a table using gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to observe a change between observation points `before` and `after` and compare the result within two groups, that is the variable `condition`. I tried this code:

```
Data %>% select(condition, before, after) %>%
  tbl_summary(by=condition) %>%
  add_p(test=everything()~"paired.wilcox.test")
```

Appears, I don't get the p-value I am looking for. I got this error, and I don't understand what it means. Can you help me?

```
There was an error in 'add_p()/add_difference()' for variable 'before', p-value omitted:
Error: 'before': There may only be one observation per `group=` per `by=` level.
There was an error in 'add_p()/add_difference()' for variable 'after', p-value omitted:
Error: 'after': There may only be one observation per `group=` per `by=` level.
```

My data

```
structure(list(condition = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1), before= c(13, 7, 18, 18, 15, 5, 14, 5, 3, 6, 
18, 7, 5, 11, 6, 3, NA, 3, 11, 8, 10, 3, 7, 7, 12, 3, 5, 8, 4, 
9, 15, 9, 3, 16, 3, 3, 11, 3, 11, 8, 14, 21, 21, 17, 9, 3, 18, 
15, 6, 6, 12, 9, 15, 5, 13, 7, 6, 7, 9, 11, 21, 12, 7, 12, 6, 
21, 15, 21, 16, 12, 7, 18, 12, 20, 3, 10), after= c(15, 
3, 6, 18, 14, 15, 6, NA, 6, 3, 18, NA, 3, 15, NA, 15, 11, NA, 
10, 9, NA, 6, 6, 12, 3, NA, NA, 11, 9, 15, 21, 21, 6, 15, 9, 
16, 9, 11, 14, 13, 5, NA, 3, 10, NA, 3, 18, 12, NA, NA, 8, 11, 
14, NA, 13, NA, NA, 10, 6, 5, 15, 11, 12, NA, 5, NA, 15, 21, 
11, NA, 3, NA, 12, NA, 17, 15)), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -76L), groups = structure(list(
    .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
        10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
        21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
        32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 
        43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
        54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
        65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
        76L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -76L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Comment: Where do you define  the function `paired.wilcox.test`? Is it from an additional package? Is your data paired? Why not simply ` add_p()`?

Comment: The wilcoxon function is from the package gtsummary, as mentioned in the header and in the tags of this question. My data is paired. Would simply 'add_p()' produce the wilcoxon test?

Comment: Where did you read that this "paired.wilcox.test" is from the package?  Yes, 'add_p()' produce the wilcoxon test if applicable.